# Install conda environment hosted on anaconda.org

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

It's possible to host `environment.yml` *files* directly on anaconda.org.  (I'm not talking about hosting packages; I'm really talking about `environment.yml` files.)  IIRC, there used to be a way to just install that directly using the `conda` command line — something like `conda install https://anaconda.org/<user>/<env-name>`.  Is this still possible?

Comment: Possible [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Why do you need to do that? In other words, more context might help you get an appropriate answer.

Comment: It's not an XY problem.  I have an environment file on my anaconda.org account that I want others to be able to install.  I used to know how to let them do that, but either I've forgotten or that behavior is no longer supported.

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anacondaorg/user-guide/tasks/work-with-environments/#downloading-your-environment-in-the-cli

Comment: Ah, yes.  That's it exactly!  Thank you.  Feel free to answer, and I'll happily accept and upvote.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `conda env create`.

The example from the [Anaconda documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anacondaorg/user-guide/tasks/work-with-environments/#downloading-your-environment-in-the-cli) ("Downloading your environment in the CLI") demonstrates the syntax:

```
# Replace <MY_ENVIRONMENT> with the name of your environment
conda env create user/<MY_ENVIRONMENT>
source activate <MY_ENVIRONMENT>
```

Here's the [documentation for the `conda env create` subcommand](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/env/create.html). The `remote_definition` positional arg is the one we're using here.